# Web Scraping the html table at https://www.mohfw.gov.in/ using python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a situation where I am webscrapin the html table at https://www.mohfw.gov.in/ which was working fine until yesteraday. now the table has been updated with multiple headers and I am not sure how can I update my code to fetcht the data.

My current code looks like the following and it was working fine before yesterday when the changes were not made to the tableat the the webpage:

```
import requests
import re
import os.path
from os import path
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
import scrape
url = 'https://www.mohfw.gov.in/'
web_content = requests.get(url).content
# parse the html content
soup = BeautifulSoup(web_content, "html.parser")
extract_contents = lambda row: [x.text.replace('\n', '') for x in row]
#find all table rows and data cells within
stats = [] 
all_rows = soup.find_all('tr')
for row in all_rows:
     stat = extract_contents(row.find_all('td')) 
if len(stat) == 3:
    stats.append(stat)
#now convert the data into a pandas dataframe for further processing
new_cols = ["Sr.No","States_UT","Confirmed","Recovered","Deaths","ActiveCases"]
india_state_data = pd.DataFrame(data = stats, columns = new_cols)
india_state_data.drop(['Sr.No'],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

this code was giving me the clean data as of day before yesterday. Any advice as to how can I update my code to fetch the new table structure?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your job is now much easier. When you analyse the website, the website makes an ajax call to load the table data.

The following script saves the json data to a file. The beauty is you don't need to pass anything to get this data. This always returns the latest data.

```
import requests, json

url = 'https://www.mohfw.gov.in/data/datanew.json'
res = requests.get(url)

with open("data.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(res.json(), f)
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "sno": "2",
        "state_name": "Andaman and Nicobar Islands",
        "active": "145",
        "positive": "338",
        "cured": "192",
        "death": "1",
        "new_active": "166",
        "new_positive": "363",
        "new_cured": "196",
        "new_death": "1",
        "state_code": "35"
    },
    {
        "sno": "1",
        "state_name": "Andhra Pradesh",
        "active": "51701",
        "positive": "102349",
        "cured": "49558",
        "death": "1090",
        "new_active": "56527",
        "new_positive": "110297",
        "new_cured": "52622",
        "new_death": "1148",
        "state_code": "28"
    },
    {
        "sno": "3",
        "state_name": "Arunachal Pradesh",
        "active": "662",
        "positive": "1239",
        "cured": "574",
        "death": "3",
        "new_active": "710",
        "new_positive": "1330",
        "new_cured": "617",
        "new_death": "3",
        "state_code": "12"
    },
    {
        "sno": "4",
        "state_name": "Assam",
        "active": "8088",
        "positive": "33576",
        "cured": "25402",
        "death": "86",
        "new_active": "8241",
        "new_positive": "34947",
        "new_cured": "26618",
        "new_death": "88",
        "state_code": "18"
    },
    {
        "sno": "5",
        "state_name": "Bihar",
        "active": "13461",
        "positive": "41244",
        "cured": "27530",
        "death": "253",
        "new_active": "14718",
        "new_positive": "43843",
        "new_cured": "28856",
        "new_death": "269",
        "state_code": "10"
    },
    {
        "sno": "6",
        "state_name": "Chandigarh",
        "active": "321",
        "positive": "910",
        "cured": "575",
        "death": "14",
        "new_active": "321",
        "new_positive": "934",
        "new_cured": "599",
        "new_death": "14",
        "state_code": "04"
    },
    {
        "sno": "7",
        "state_name": "Chhattisgarh",
        "active": "2529",
        "positive": "7745",
        "cured": "5172",
        "death": "44",
        "new_active": "2772",
        "new_positive": "8257",
        "new_cured": "5439",
        "new_death": "46",
        "state_code": "22"
    },
    {
        "sno": "8",
        "state_name": "Dadra and Nagar Haveli and Daman and Diu",
        "active": "380",
        "positive": "946",
        "cured": "564",
        "death": "2",
        "new_active": "384",
        "new_positive": "982",
        "new_cured": "596",
        "new_death": "2",
        "state_code": "26"
    },
    {
        "sno": "10",
        "state_name": "Delhi",
        "active": "10994",
        "positive": "131219",
        "cured": "116372",
        "death": "3853",
        "new_active": "10887",
        "new_positive": "132275",
        "new_cured": "117507",
        "new_death": "3881",
        "state_code": "07"
    },
    {
        "sno": "11",
        "state_name": "Goa",
        "active": "1673",
        "positive": "5119",
        "cured": "3410",
        "death": "36",
        "new_active": "1656",
        "new_positive": "5287",
        "new_cured": "3595",
        "new_death": "36",
        "state_code": "30"
    },
    {
        "sno": "12",
        "state_name": "Gujarat",
        "active": "13146",
        "positive": "56874",
        "cured": "41380",
        "death": "2348",
        "new_active": "13198",
        "new_positive": "57982",
        "new_cured": "42412",
        "new_death": "2372",
        "state_code": "24"
    },
    {
        "sno": "13",
        "state_name": "Haryana",
        "active": "6684",
        "positive": "32127",
        "cured": "25046",
        "death": "397",
        "new_active": "6712",
        "new_positive": "32876",
        "new_cured": "25758",
        "new_death": "406",
        "state_code": "06"
    },
    {
        "sno": "14",
        "state_name": "Himachal Pradesh",
        "active": "1040",
        "positive": "2270",
        "cured": "1216",
        "death": "14",
        "new_active": "1082",
        "new_positive": "2330",
        "new_cured": "1234",
        "new_death": "14",
        "state_code": "02"
    },
    {
        "sno": "15",
        "state_name": "Jammu and Kashmir",
        "active": "7667",
        "positive": "18390",
        "cured": "10402",
        "death": "321",
        "new_active": "7661",
        "new_positive": "18879",
        "new_cured": "10885",
        "new_death": "333",
        "state_code": "01"
    },
    {
        "sno": "16",
        "state_name": "Jharkhand",
        "active": "4824",
        "positive": "8683",
        "cured": "3770",
        "death": "89",
        "new_active": "5121",
        "new_positive": "9078",
        "new_cured": "3868",
        "new_death": "89",
        "state_code": "20"
    },
    {
        "sno": "17",
        "state_name": "Karnataka",
        "active": "61827",
        "positive": "101465",
        "cured": "37685",
        "death": "1953",
        "new_active": "64442",
        "new_positive": "107001",
        "new_cured": "40504",
        "new_death": "2055",
        "state_code": "29"
    },
    {
        "sno": "18",
        "state_name": "Kerala",
        "active": "9619",
        "positive": "19727",
        "cured": "10045",
        "death": "63",
        "new_active": "10103",
        "new_positive": "20894",
        "new_cured": "10724",
        "new_death": "67",
        "state_code": "32"
    },
    {
        "sno": "19",
        "state_name": "Ladakh",
        "active": "236",
        "positive": "1306",
        "cured": "1066",
        "death": "4",
        "new_active": "254",
        "new_positive": "1327",
        "new_cured": "1067",
        "new_death": "6",
        "state_code": "37"
    },
    {
        "sno": "20",
        "state_name": "Lakshadweep",
        "active": "0",
        "positive": "0",
        "cured": "0",
        "death": "0",
        "new_active": "0",
        "new_positive": "0",
        "new_cured": "0",
        "new_death": "0",
        "state_code": "31"
    },
    {
        "sno": "21",
        "state_name": "Madhya Pradesh",
        "active": "7978",
        "positive": "28589",
        "cured": "19791",
        "death": "820",
        "new_active": "8044",
        "new_positive": "29217",
        "new_cured": "20343",
        "new_death": "830",
        "state_code": "23"
    },
    {
        "sno": "22",
        "state_name": "Maharashtra",
        "active": "147896",
        "positive": "383723",
        "cured": "221944",
        "death": "13883",
        "new_active": "144998",
        "new_positive": "391440",
        "new_cured": "232277",
        "new_death": "14165",
        "state_code": "27"
    },
    {
        "sno": "23",
        "state_name": "Manipur",
        "active": "690",
        "positive": "2286",
        "cured": "1596",
        "death": "0",
        "new_active": "705",
        "new_positive": "2317",
        "new_cured": "1612",
        "new_death": "0",
        "state_code": "14"
    },
    {
        "sno": "24",
        "state_name": "Meghalaya",
        "active": "547",
        "positive": "738",
        "cured": "186",
        "death": "5",
        "new_active": "580",
        "new_positive": "779",
        "new_cured": "194",
        "new_death": "5",
        "state_code": "17"
    },
    {
        "sno": "25",
        "state_name": "Mizoram",
        "active": "191",
        "positive": "384",
        "cured": "193",
        "death": "0",
        "new_active": "186",
        "new_positive": "384",
        "new_cured": "198",
        "new_death": "0",
        "state_code": "15"
    },
    {
        "sno": "26",
        "state_name": "Nagaland",
        "active": "811",
        "positive": "1385",
        "cured": "569",
        "death": "5",
        "new_active": "878",
        "new_positive": "1460",
        "new_cured": "577",
        "new_death": "5",
        "state_code": "13"
    },
    {
        "sno": "27",
        "state_name": "Odisha",
        "active": "9371",
        "positive": "26892",
        "cured": "17374",
        "death": "147",
        "new_active": "9892",
        "new_positive": "28107",
        "new_cured": "18061",
        "new_death": "154",
        "state_code": "21"
    },
    {
        "sno": "28",
        "state_name": "Puducherry",
        "active": "1109",
        "positive": "2872",
        "cured": "1720",
        "death": "43",
        "new_active": "1182",
        "new_positive": "3011",
        "new_cured": "1782",
        "new_death": "47",
        "state_code": "34"
    },
    {
        "sno": "29",
        "state_name": "Punjab",
        "active": "4387",
        "positive": "13769",
        "cured": "9064",
        "death": "318",
        "new_active": "4290",
        "new_positive": "14378",
        "new_cured": "9752",
        "new_death": "336",
        "state_code": "03"
    },
    {
        "sno": "30",
        "state_name": "Rajasthan",
        "active": "10124",
        "positive": "36878",
        "cured": "26123",
        "death": "631",
        "new_active": "10668",
        "new_positive": "38514",
        "new_cured": "27202",
        "new_death": "644",
        "state_code": "08"
    },
    {
        "sno": "31",
        "state_name": "Sikkim",
        "active": "380",
        "positive": "555",
        "cured": "174",
        "death": "1",
        "new_active": "392",
        "new_positive": "579",
        "new_cured": "186",
        "new_death": "1",
        "state_code": "11"
    },
    {
        "sno": "32",
        "state_name": "Tamil Nadu",
        "active": "54896",
        "positive": "220716",
        "cured": "162249",
        "death": "3571",
        "new_active": "57073",
        "new_positive": "227688",
        "new_cured": "166956",
        "new_death": "3659",
        "state_code": "33"
    },
    {
        "sno": "34",
        "state_name": "Telengana***",
        "active": "13753",
        "positive": "57142",
        "cured": "42909",
        "death": "480",
        "new_active": "13753",
        "new_positive": "57142",
        "new_cured": "42909",
        "new_death": "480",
        "state_code": "36"
    },
    {
        "sno": "33",
        "state_name": "Tripura",
        "active": "1565",
        "positive": "4049",
        "cured": "2467",
        "death": "17",
        "new_active": "1627",
        "new_positive": "4269",
        "new_cured": "2621",
        "new_death": "21",
        "state_code": "16"
    },
    {
        "sno": "35",
        "state_name": "Uttarakhand",
        "active": "2587",
        "positive": "6328",
        "cured": "3675",
        "death": "66",
        "new_active": "2797",
        "new_positive": "6587",
        "new_cured": "3720",
        "new_death": "70",
        "state_code": "05"
    },
    {
        "sno": "36",
        "state_name": "Uttar Pradesh",
        "active": "26204",
        "positive": "70493",
        "cured": "42833",
        "death": "1456",
        "new_active": "27934",
        "new_positive": "73951",
        "new_cured": "44520",
        "new_death": "1497",
        "state_code": "09"
    },
    {
        "sno": "37",
        "state_name": "West Bengal",
        "active": "19502",
        "positive": "60803",
        "cured": "39917",
        "death": "1411",
        "new_active": "19493",
        "new_positive": "62964",
        "new_cured": "42022",
        "new_death": "1449",
        "state_code": "19"
    },
    {
        "sno": "11111",
        "state_name": "",
        "active": "496988",
        "positive": "1483156",
        "cured": "952743",
        "death": "33425",
        "new_active": "509447",
        "new_positive": "1531669",
        "new_cured": "988029",
        "new_death": "34193",
        "state_code": ""
    }
]
```

Comment: that makes sense. but I want to save the results in a pandas data-frame eventually. How would I do that? I have no previous experience with json.

Comment: it is resolved now! tried this : df_in = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(json_normalize(data), orient='columns') and it worked :) thanks!

Comment: Is there any way to download the total historical database from this website? So I can analyze the day wise change?